# How to interact with the chaincode (installed using composer) through peer node cli?

Tags: hyperledger-fabric, hyperledger, hyperledger-composer

I had developed an application using composer. But it is now deprecated. So i'm trying at least to use the chaincode generated using composer.

Is it possible to interact with the chaincode generated using composer through 'peer chaincode' command?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Composer doesn't `generate` chaincode. A business network is tightly bound to the composer framework. A business network is an implementation written to the composer specification and contains the composer runtime to understand and interpret that implementation at runtime. Therefore a Composer Business network is not standalone chaincode.

The client side of composer for client application provides the necessary operational tools as well as the business application apis in order to correctly interact with a business network. Although technically you could work out how to invoke a business network from client code without using composer it would not be trivial.